# Bind a chart series

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, charts

in my WinApp I use how MySql datasource the DataReader.Now, I would like to use a DevExpress Xchart control but I don't know how to do to bind a series or to make a parametric query with DateTime Controls.

There is sombody that may help me?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

[This page on the DevExpress help site has all of the information you need...](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument3095)